# How to use library indexing for dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I know that certain functions are possible to use only when library is loaded.

For example to use raster function from raster package I need to:

```
library(raster)
raster("msi1986.img") #see the summary of img.file in working directory
```

Or...

I can indicate the library without loading it (by using **name of library::function**)

```
raster::raster("msi1986.img")
```

Both ways produce the same results.

My problem is that I can not use **name of library::function** for dplyr package.

Part of my script looks like this:

```
# rescaling table via "dplyr"
library(dplyr)
my.df.R = betw_frame %>%
    group_by(id) %>% # group by id
    mutate(value = value - min(value), value = value - lag(value)) %>% # group min to 0, difference lag 1
    na.omit %>% # remove NA caused by lag 1 differencing
    arrange(id, value) %>% # order by value within each id
    mutate(time = 1:length(value)) %>% # Make a time variable from 1 to 5 based on current order
    select(-year) # remove year column to match final OP output
```

I tried **this** but it is not working.

```
my.df.R = betw_frame dplyr::%>%
    group_by(id) dplyr::%>% # group by id
    mutate(value = value - min(value), value = value - lag(value)) dplyr::%>% # group min to 0, difference lag 1
    na.omit dplyr::%>% # remove NA caused by lag 1 differencing
    arrange(id, value) dplyr::%>% # order by value within each id
    mutate(time = 1:length(value)) dplyr::%>% # Make a time variable from 1 to 5 based on current order
    select(-year) # remove year column to match final OP output
```

**Is there a way how to indicate library other than dplyr::%>% ?**

Reproducible example can be found in my previous question and answer by @aosmith [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761835/how-to-apply-a-set-of-functions-to-each-group-of-a-grouping-variable-in-r-data-f).

Comment: You would also need to make use of `dplyr::` for all the other functions from dplyr like `group_by`, `mutate`, `arrange` etc.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? You didn't provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: At the very least you'd need to wrap the function in quotes. This works: `dplyr::'%>%'(1:10, head)`.